# Override CSS command?

Tags: css, slider

I'm using a slider plugin for WordPress, a very nice one, but for some reason the programmers seem to have missed a very obvious feature.

I want a piece of dynamic content to appear in the bottom left corner of the slide, the text block will change size so to stop it spilling off the edge I want to place the CSS command bottom:10px; unfortunately the designers have only given the options of top and left to decide placement. They've got a text area for custom code, but when I ask it to do bottom:10px; although it works in the preview, when it's live on the front page, the slider automatically inputs top:0px; making the text block stretch over the entire slider. Very messy indeed!

So what I need to know is there a way of tell top:0px to sod off? I know with many of these kinds of things I can implement a display:none; or overwrite the original command with !important. But in this case I need to stop top:0px; being called at all.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
top: auto !important;
```